# GWT + JDO + ArrayList

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, arraylist, jdo

I'm getting a Null ArrayList in a program i'm developing. For testing purposes I created this really small example that still has the same problem. I already tried diferent Primary Keys, but the problem persists.

Any ideas or suggestions?

**1-Employee class**

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Employee {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String key;

    @Persistent
    private ArrayList<String> nicks;

    public Employee(ArrayList<String> nicks) {
        this.setNicks(nicks);
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setNicks(ArrayList<String> nicks) {
        this.nicks = nicks;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNicks() {
        return nicks;
    } 
}
```

**2-EmployeeService**

```
public class BookServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
EmployeeService {

    public void addEmployee(){

        ArrayList<String> nicks = new ArrayList<String>();
        nicks.add("name1");
        nicks.add("name2");

        Employee employee = new Employee(nicks);

        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            pm.makePersistent(employee);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return
     * @throws NotLoggedInException
     * @gwt.typeArgs <Employee>
     */
    public Collection<Employee> getEmployees() {

        PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();

        try {
            Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM " + Employee.class.getName());

            Collection<Employee> list =
                pm.detachCopyAll((Collection<Employee>)q.execute());

            return list;

        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Employee class did not have detachable = "true".

You should change

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
```

to

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it significant that in `addEmployee`, you obtain the persistenceManager like this:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
```

but in getEmployees you call it like this

```
PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
```

without using `PMF.get()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No, it's not significant. It was just a copy-paste error. But it's exactly the same thing. I've changed it anyway and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code a bit, and everything is normal now, still I don't know what caused this problem.

I'm using Lists now instead of the collections**(1)**, I return everything as a simple array trough the RPC**(2)** and I changed the way I did the query**(3)**.

**(1)** List results = (List) query.execute();

**(2)** return (Employee[]) employees.toArray(new Employee[0]);

**(3)** Query query = pm.newQuery(Employee.class);